# how to put the condition which set the template url to load

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I would like to have two main pages (logged in, logged out), which have url like '/'.

Is it posiible to do it with ngRoute? 
I was searching the soltion but everywhere was to use ui-router.

Now I have sth like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  if ( next.$$route.orginalPath == '/' && loggedIn ) {
     next.$$route.templateUrl = "app/main/main-loggedIn.html"
  } else {
     next.$$route.templateUrl = "app/main/main-loggedOut.html"
  }
});
```

and

```
angular.module('name').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main-loggedOut.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
  });
```

but it doesn't work well. It changes the templateURL but it get data before that changings and load always loggedOut page.

I have also the solution to put both html in one file in set them ng-if, but I prefer to avoid it.

**solution:**

main.html

```
<div ng-include="mainTemplate"></div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('bookkeepingApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/', { controller: 'MainCtrl', templateUrl: "app/main/main.html" })
}).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Auth) {
   $scope.$watch(function($scope) {
      return $scope.mainTemplate = Auth.isLoggedIn() ? 'app/main/main-loggedIn.html' : 'app/main/main-loggedOut.html';
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a template within a template, i.e in your route "/" you have a

```
<div ng-include="scopeVariable">

</div>
```

the scope variable points to a loggedin/loggedout page depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're getting the `loggedIn` value, but `templateUrl` accepts a function as value, you just have to return the correct one, based on the information of the user. I guess the code above might work.

```
angular.module('name').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      templateUrl: function() {
        return loggedIn ? "app/main/main-loggedIn.html" : "app/main/main-loggedOut.html"
      }
   })
 });
```

Comment: it is exacly what i need, but I unfortunately cannot get the loggedIn value. I use angular-fullstack generator and Auth where is loggedIn defined, but i cannot inject it to config function :/

Comment: @AniaLasocka Can't you put in the `$rootScope`?

Comment: i could, but when i declare $rootScope.logged = loggedIn; in $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart') function and i try to call it in $routeProvider i get undefined :/